# What is the meaning of "out of the blue"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please I wanna know what the phrase "out of the blue" means. I've heard this phrase in Adele's song and I don't know what she meant

Comment: You could easily answer your own question by doing a very simple Google search. Follow this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_blue_(idiom) Generally, according to one of this website's rules, basic things like definitions of words and expressions should be answered by consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**out of the blue**" is a shortening of the phrase "**like a bolt from the blue**", and is usually phrased as "**(to be) hit/struck out of the blue**". The idea is that the event in question is occurring like a lightning strike on a clear, sunny day - if there was a thunderstorm, people would take cover and be prepared, but instead the lightning is coming out of nowhere. It's completely unexpected and nobody was prepared for this to happen.